# How to use AVAudioRecorder data and convert it to raw audio for C++?

Tags: objective-c, audio, core-audio

I've been looking up on where to get microphone input in mac and the AVAudioRecorder class from Objective C turned up. I've managed to record audio into a file, but how can I use AVAudioRecorder and then convert it's Core Audio Format data into raw audio to use in C++ code, for example PocketSphinx? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Audio Queue API and the RemoteIO Audio Unit will allow getting raw audio sample buffers from the microphone on iOS devices.

Comment: Can you provide an example for this, please?

Comment: Examples not short.  Search this site for already existing references to books, web sites, Apple documentation and sample code for either API.

Comment: This loses a benefit of AVAudioRecorder, namely levels. For example, this project https://github.com/fulldecent/FDSoundActivatedRecorder uses levels to decide when to stop recording which is simple with AVAudioRecorder

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796064/avaudiorecorder-initwithurl-file-type-documentation